# JPQL Query Error - hibernate many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I want to printout all 'Cuentas?' that has a client name 'Paco': 
I have this entity:

```java
public class Cuenta implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cuentasC",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Cliente> clientesC = new HashSet<Cliente>();
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "CLIENTE")
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "Nombre", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String Nombre_C;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Cuenta> cuentasC = new HashSet<Cuenta>();
}
```

And I have this query getting this error:

```java
String q = "select c FROM CUENTA c, IN (cuentas.clientesC) cli "+"WHERE CLIENTE cli.Nombre = 'Paco' ";
Query query = em.createQuery(q);
List<Cuenta> resultado = query.getResultList();
System.out.println(resultado.toString());
```

Showing this error that i couln't find why is wrong:

```
unexpected token: cli near line 1, column 76 [select c FROM entidades.Cuenta c, IN (cuentas.clientesC) cli WHERE CLIENTE cli.Nombre = 'Paco' ]
unexpected token: cli near line 1, column 76 [select c FROM entidades.Cuenta c, IN (cuentas.clientesC) cli WHERE CLIENTE cli.Nombre = 'Paco' ]
```

It could be a syntax error? Could be a problem with the direction of the relationships?

Comment: `select c FROM entidades.Cuenta c, IN (cuentas.clientesC) cli WHERE CLIENTE cli.Nombre = 'Paco'` not once you define `cli`. Replace it with just `c` as you defined `c`as alias for `entidades.Cuenta`

Comment: But if i put this ``` select c FROM entidades.Cuenta c, IN (cuentas.clientesC) cli WHERE CLIENTE c.Nombre = 'Paco'  ``` I haven't ot a field call "Nombre"

Comment: because you called the field `Nombre_C`. you cant mix HQL and SQL like that

Comment: OK. Problem solved, thanks for the help :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved and upgraded:
Select all "CUENTA" that have Saldo greater that 10 and a "CLIENTE.name" = 'Paco'

```
String q = "select c FROM CUENTA c, IN (c.clientesC) clientesC "
                    +"WHERE clientesC.Nombre_C = 'Paco' AND c.Saldo > 10";
```